# Badge number is misaligned with badge icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: shot]

See above: the "1" refers to the silver badges, but it's closer to the bronze badges. 
The larger spacing should be *after* the number and not *before*.

Comment: Good spot. On my browser (Chrome beta channel) they are also vertically mis-aligned (count midline higher than badge midline).

Comment: It also happens in the user flair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pushed a fix for this to dev. The change will be on live after the next production build(within 24hours)

Comment: Excellent! I really like how you guys involve the humble community for pretty much everything. It's paying off too. More and more web searches I do yield an SE site in the top ten.

Answer (score 5):

I agree. I also fixed it:

[image: Fixed Badges]

Change CSS to:

```
.badge1 {-95px -402px;}
.badge2 {-71px -402px;}
.badge3 {-47px -402px;}
```

Simply decrease the first values by 4 or 5 px.

Comment: thanks! I used your css for the fix.